# Grub failed to install to /dev/md0 on Ubuntu 18 to 20 upgrade

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, partitioning, grub2, upgrade

I ran `do-release-upgrade` on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server. It looked like the upgrade to 20.04 LTS was successful, but then at what I'm assuming is the end of the upgrade, I am presented with this message:

[image: Grub failed to install to the following devices: /dev/md0 - Do you want to continue anyway? If you do, your computer may not start up properly. Writing GRUB to boot device failed - continue?]

Where do I go from here?

Follow up questions:

1. If I select "No", what will happen? Would it abort the install? If so, what can I do to tell the upgrade to install grub to the correct location on the next attempt?
2. Since I still have shell access to the server, is there anything I can do to fix this so that I can instead confidentially select "Yes"?  I'm assuming it's not as simple as manually running `grub-install` since that would be running from Ubuntu 18.04 and would not install the correct grub, right?

`parted -l` output:

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1024GB  1024GB

Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1000GB  1000GB

Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1000GB  1000GB  ext4
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-cb309216:50f46df5:a8c1735b:a59e61b4 / ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G  8.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.1M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/md0        916G  107G  763G  13% /
tmpfs            16G   16K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20290
/dev/loop1       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/loop2       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2105
/dev/loop3      112M  112M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24322
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /var/snap/lxd/common/ns
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

I assume that what confused the upgrade is because there's not a separate partition for `/boot`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to simply reply with "Yes" and allow the system to finish the upgrade and reboot. It booted up fine.

Had it not booted up, my plan was to boot from an Ubuntu 20.04 thumb drive and manually install grub to `/dev/sda` (and `/dev/sdb`).

I didn't end up needing to do that, so I can't say exactly how it would go, but I suspect it would have involved manually mounting `/dev/md0` and then chrooting to that and then running this:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

UPDATE: A better solution would have been to open a terminal before hitting "Yes" and installing grub using the above commands. (Thanks to @user10489 for explaining that during an upgrade, the Ubuntu 18 OS/environment is far enough replaced with Ubuntu 20 that grub-install will do the right thing.)

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to run the grub install command (above) from a terminal window before answering yes...   that way it won't fail to boot.  It also doesn't hurt to install the grub boot sector to multiple disks, then you have a backup and some bios's will let you choose.  If I was doing this from the installer instead of an upgrade, I might chroot to teh install partition before running grub, but for an upgrade it's easier.

Comment: @user10489, thanks for the comment. Since a terminal window would have still been running in the Ubuntu 18 environment, I wasn't sure if simply running the grub-install from there would work.

Comment: Unless you are using containers, there is no "ubuntu 18" environment.  It's one environment that is modified on the fliy.  New commands will use the updated binaries.  Old processes (like your preexisting shell) may still be running the old versions, but likely that doesn't matter in the short term before you reboot anyway and old shells still run new commands.

Comment: @user10489, good to know! Knowing that the upgrade process directly overwrites the old OS is really helpful information. I guess that makes any type of rollback impossible, but certainly makes situations like this a lot less complicated. I've updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: The upgrade process doesn't exactly overwrite the old OS.  More like it installs new stuff and afterwards deletes some of the old stuff and some deleted stuff remains in memory until reboot, and autoremove at any time in the future may remove the rest of the old stuff.   It's possible, especially with Ubuntu, to have a mix of old and new stuff in the upgraded result without this causing any problems.

Comment: Gotcha. I've clarified the UPDATE section of my answer.